# Regular expression to validate Jordanian National Number

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, validation

I'm try to write a regular expression that validate Jordanian national number/ Identity.

The Identity is made up by concatenating from the Identity owner information
For example for the following identity `98610589069` is made up of;

- `986` = Year of birth (`1986`)
- `1` = Gender. (`1` means male, `2`
  means female)
- `05` = refer to the city of birth.
- `89096` = refer to the incremental number for total born in that year, in that city.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It is not a question, and just I want to share my knowledge. Because I spent a time to write this regex, and I want to save others, developers offer.

Comment: If it is "self answered question" please make sure to split it into proper question and proper answer. As post stands now it is question without any question in it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
^[90][0-9]{2}[12][0-9]{2}[0-9]{5}$
```

What it'll do is

```
[90][0-9]{2} - matches 000 to 999 (year 1900 to year 2099, assuming the date range)
[12] - matches 1 or 2 for gender
[0-9]{2} - matches 00 to 99 (assuming city code 00 - 99)
[0-9]{5} - 5 digit sequence number
```

Here are working demos at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rS3rT5/1) and [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/3bv8o).

So, the main issues I see in your `Regex` are
(1) You are not matching city code
(2) You are taking last part as length = 6

Comment: @YazanFahadHaddadein It works (as expected) here at `regexr` http://www.regexr.com/3bv8o as well. When you test, use "98610589069" without spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `^[0-9]{3}[12][0-9]{7}$`